# Word break doesn't work in FF and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, line-breaks

I have faced a problem with `word-wrap: break-word;` property in IE and FF.
In Chrome the text looks good, if it overflows its parent Chrome tries to split text by spaces and if it has no spaces Chrome just break all the word:

[image]

But in IE and FF this rule doesn't work

[image]

I can add `break-all` in this case the browser spit the union word but it doesn't look good with the words that have spaces

[image]

Comment: Which versions of FF and IE are you targeting? Could you also supply relevant HTML and CSS code please?

Comment: Screen shots by themselves are not enough. Post an example of the code you used. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hLne3z3p/) I made works fine in SeaMonkey.

Comment: You have answer in your question: ``word-break break-word`` doesn't work in IE and FF because it's unofficial webkit value: http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` seems to be working on Firefox 39 and IE 11. Which version are you targeting? Made a simple example to test: http://plnkr.co/edit/xGm5f21ZV1fAebEp8onq?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `word-wrap: break-word;` isn't always the good solution while breaking overflowing sentences. As it breaks the words of the sentence which remove the actual meaning of the word OR better to say make it unreadable.

So while using `word-wrap: break-word;` try considering `white-space: pre-wrap;` which only breaks the sentence the meaningfully that means the word *accessibility* can break into

> access
>  ibility

but if we use `white-space: pre-wrap;` it will always give you

> accessibility

Here I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/hLne3z3p/1).

```
p {word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

Hope it will work for you.